# saving the a value from an xml parsing result and pass it to the other page

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

I used DOM parser to parse an xml result I get from a webservice query. I save the results in a hashmap in then in one Arraylist in order to display it in a listview AND THEN retrieve their values from the textview and save them in strings in order to pass them on to the other page WHEN the user click on a single listview item. HOWEVER, I have on value the I'm retrieving from the webservice that I DON'T want to display it in the textview, I just want to save it and pass it to the other page when the user clicks on the listview item. I don't know how to do it, because the way I've done it with the other values is by getting the values out of the textview in the listview. How can I get the value of "Persistent_ID" from the Arraylist and pass it to the other page when the user chooses a listitem.

This is my code:

```
public void receiveResults4(Context context, String result3) {

    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf
                = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(result3));
        Document doc = db.parse(is);

        //All the UDSObjects
        NodeList nodesUDSObjectList = doc.getElementsByTagName("UDSObject");

        // iterate the UDSObjects
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nodesUDSObjectList.getLength(); i++) {
            Element elementUDSObject = (Element) nodesUDSObjectList.item(i);
            //You have a UDSObjects now
            NodeList nodesAttributeList = elementUDSObject.getElementsByTagName("Attribute");
      //You have a list of the attributes for UDSObject(i)

      // iterate the Attributes of the elementUDSObject(i)
            HashMap<String, String> mapp = new HashMap<String, String>();

            for (int iA = 0; iA < nodesAttributeList.getLength(); iA++) {
                Element elementAttribute = (Element) nodesAttributeList.item(iA);
    //You have attribute(iA)

                NodeList AttrNameElementList = (NodeList) elementAttribute.getElementsByTagName("AttrName");
                String nameValue = getCharacterDataFromElement((Element) (AttrNameElementList.item(0)));

                NodeList AttrValueElementList = (NodeList) elementAttribute.getElementsByTagName("AttrValue");
                String valueValue = getCharacterDataFromElement((Element) (AttrValueElementList.item(0)));

                if (nameValue.equals("ref_num")) {
                    mapp.put(REF_NUM, valueValue);
                }

                if (nameValue.equals("summary")) {
                    mapp.put(SUMMARY, valueValue);
                }

                //THIS IS THE VALUE THAT I WANT TO SAVE AND PASS WITHOUT DISPLAYING IT IN THE LISTVIEW
                if (nameValue.equals("persistent_id")) {
                    valSetOne.add(valueValue);
                    mapp.put(Persistent_ID, valueValue);
                }

            }

            menuItems.add(mapp);

        }

     // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.listview_ticket,
                new String[]{REF_NUM, SUMMARY}, new int[]{
                    R.id.ticketnumberbutton, R.id.summaryeg});

        setListAdapter(adapter);
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // listening to single listitem click
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

               // getting values from selected ListItem
                String refnum = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ticketnumberbutton)).getText().toString();

                String summary = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.summaryeg)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewRequest.class
                );
                in.putExtra(REF_NUM, refnum);

                in.putExtra(SUMMARY, summary);

                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
    }
}
```